# Mounting NTFS USB drive on Debian with ntfs-3g

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, usb-drive, ntfs-3g

I formatted a USB drive with NTFS on Win and I'd like to use it on Debian. When I try to mount it by clicking the icon in Thunar, I get `Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:.`

So I created a new directory called sdd1 in /media and then as sudo I ran `mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1` which mounted the drive. I can read and write there, however if I try to delete a file, I get `Unable to find or create trash directory`

When I try to unmount the device via GUI, I get `Error unmounting: umount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: umount: /dev/sdd1 mount disagrees with the fstab`

The /etc/fstab contains this line

```
/dev/sdd1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

Should I just change usb0 to sdd1 (hopefully FAT sticks will keep working) or is there more to be done?

Comment: Why does it need to be in `/etc/fstab`? You appear to just be mounting it as needed and don't require it to be there at boot. Just remove the line or comment it out.

Comment: That's true, I don't need it. Thanks!